# How to use {{string}} to assign a value to an attribute in input tag (Twig Template)

Tags: 8, theming

I want to do the following:

```
{% set var= "string"%}

<input name='{{var}}' />
```

All drupal does is to ignore the tag in gerneral.

If i set the tag like this everything is fine:

```
<input name='string' />
```

Setting the attribute using equals the same result (ignoring the tag):

```
<input {{ attributes.setAttribute('name', var ) }} />
```

Comment: Don't create forms in a twig file. Drupal has its own Form API which is relatively easy to use, and has built-in security, you just need to do a bit of reading beforehand. The API doc: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api

Comment: Clearly `{{var}}` is not what you think it is. Perhaps its empty or it contains html markup.

Comment: if i render the content of var i get exactly what i put there: "string" - just when assigning it to the attribute it fails to render...

Comment: when i assign the var to any other thing then the input attributes it renders... i tried using a <div name='{{var}}'> and the result is just fine

Comment: That's funky, what template file is this?

Comment: Did you use the twig function {% set attribute = create_attribute() %}?
Are you sure {{ attribute }} works?